# Twig - convert time from one format to another

Tags: php, twig

I am pulling in a time from a database in the following format `10:00:00`

I would like to be able to display this in the following format... `10am`

Here's my twig code ...

`{{ item.item_start_time }}`

Any ideas how i can to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow the [twig documentation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/date.html). It should be:

```
{{ item.item_start_time|date("ha") }}
```

For the format specifiers which I'm using, please refer to the documentation of [`date`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
$date = '14:00:00';
echo date('hA', strtotime($date));
echo "</br>";
echo date('HA', strtotime($date));
```

Output

```
02PM
14PM
```

> h 12-hour format of an hour with leading zeros    01 through 12
>
> H 24-hour format of an hour with leading zeros    00 through 23

Reference [date function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Reference Answer on StackOverflow [Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3400324/how-to-convert-time-like-2-pm-or-3-am-to-hhmmss-format-in-php)